# react native fetch not getting the same content as post man

Tags: javascript, react-native, fetch

Im having a little problem with my request on getting an html from `https://readnovelfull.com/beauty-and-the-beast-wolf-hubby-xoxo/chapter-1-i-would-not-be-responsible.html` as example.

I can get all the html on the other url eg novel detalj, latest upgated etc.

but not when im getting the detali for the chapters.

I tested those url on `postman` and also on `https://codebeautify.org/source-code-viewer` as well and there is no problem on getting the content of the chapter of which it exist under the div `#chr-content`

So I am a bit lost now, what am I doing wrong?

Here is my fetch calls which is working on other novel sites.

```
  static async getHtml(
    url: string
  ): Promise<HTMLDivElement> {
    console.log(`Sending html request to ${url}`);
    var container = parse('<div>test</div>') as any;
    try {
      let headers = new Headers({
        Accept: '*/*',
        'User-Agent':
          'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.141 Safari/537.36'
      });

      var data = await fetch(url, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: headers,
      });
      if (!data.ok) {
        const message = `An error has occured:${data.status}`;
        console.log(message);
      } else {
        var html = await data.text();
        console.log('Data is ok. proceed to parse it');
        container = parse('<div>' + html + '</div>') as any;
      }
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
    return container as HTMLDivElement;
  }
```

I should mention that am not getting any error what so ever, its just that the html I am getting is not the same as postman and other site is getting.

**Update**

Ok so i did some research on the site and this is what i come up with.

the site need `X-CSRF-TOKEN` and i was able to extract those and find those values

```
const csrf = 'x09Q6KGqJOJJx2iHwNQUa_mYfG4neV9EOOMsUBKTItKfNjSc0thQzwf2HvCR7SQCqfIpC2ogPj18jG4dQPgVtQ==';
const id = 774791;
```

which i need to send a request to `https://readnovelfull.com/ajax/increase-chapter-views` with the values above. and this will send back `true/false`

now i tried to inc the `csrf` on my fetch call after but its still the same old same no data.

any idee if i am doing something wrong still?

Comment: So you're getting a valid HTML response and not an error page or something, it's just not the same actual content? Have you tried changing the [redirect mode](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-request-redirect-mode) to see if you're getting redirected somewhere?

Comment: Yes its exactly that. and i dont know about redirect mode. as i said that it work well on postman. could you test and see ?

Comment: No, I'm not going to spin up a project to test your code... that's on you to do, I was just suggesting something you could check out.

Comment: I have tested redirect attr on cockes and its not working

Comment: @ Zac Anger see the update please and see if you could help.

Comment: I tried this and compared the result with the one in **codebeautify.org**, The only different I see is div section of `(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});` which occurs two times. Is that what is missing or it's something else?

Comment: @AshutoshDubey Did you find the div `#chr-content`

Comment: Yes, One that has `<h3>Chapter 1: I Would Not Be Responsible</h3>...`?

Comment: What??? Did you use my code? and did you test this on an android mobile or emulator?

Comment: This line `<div id="chr-content" class="chr-c" style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif, serif; font-size: 18px; line-height: 160%;">` right? I checked on android mobile, codebeautify.org and from chrome **right click -> View page source**. what's wrong?

Comment: When i test this on an android, i doint get the complete html. `chr-content` is missing.

Comment: `console.log(container);` before return I can see this **chr-content** div on logs and code is pretty much same. I'm using react-native version 0.63.3.

Comment: Shit I really dont understand, will have some time to test it then agen

Comment: I can post answer, will share screenshot of the log for you to confirm and I also can get part of `(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});` too now.

Comment: Ok guys, I found the problem :) `node-html-parser` fail to parse the html..

Comment: Yes, Offcouse :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you have an issue with CORS. To make sure just try to send request through [cors proxy](https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/). One of the ways you can quickly do that is add prefix URL:

[https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://readnovelfull.com/beauty-and-the-beast-wolf-hubby-xoxo/chapter-1-i-would-not-be-responsible.html`](https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://readnovelfull.com/beauty-and-the-beast-wolf-hubby-xoxo/chapter-1-i-would-not-be-responsible.html%60)

> NOTE: Using this CORS proxy on production is not recommended, because it's not secure

If after that you'll receive data, that means that you faced with CORS, and you need to figure out how to solve it in your specific case.

#### Reproducable example:

```js
const parse = (str) => str;

const getHtml = async (url) => {
    console.log(`Sending html request to ${url}`);
    var container = parse('<div>No content =(</div>')
    try {
      let headers = new Headers({
        Accept: '*/*',
        'User-Agent':
          'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.141 Safari/537.36'
      });
      var data = await fetch(url, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: headers,
      });
      if (!data.ok) {
        const message = `An error has occured:${data.status}`;
        console.log(message);
      } else {
        var html = await data.text();
        console.log('Data is ok. proceed to parse it');
        container = parse('<div>' + html + '</div>');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
    return container;
  }

getHtml('https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://readnovelfull.com/beauty-and-the-beast-wolf-hubby-xoxo/chapter-1-i-would-not-be-responsible.html').then(htmlContent => document.querySelector('div').innerHTML = htmlContent);
```

```html
<div>loading...</div>
```

If it doesn't help, please provide a reproducible RN example, but I believe there is no difference between RN and web environments in that case.

Comment: Come on man, I offered 100 point. I need a solution that work on react-native android. create a quake react-native on android online and see if you could solve it

Comment: Hmmm... so you tested proposed solution or just write this comment?

Comment: Its not a core problem. and i have really not tested this. because its not a solution. as I said that on web fetch is able to get the data but when you test this on react native android. there you have a problem

Comment: You didn't say it, and you only mentioned postman and it's web analogue